# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xyz' " after doing pip install xyz

Tags: python, macos, pip

I have a project where I need to import a table in my code in Python 3,7 and for that I am using the `openpyx` library on a mac. However I don't understand how to install it.

In my textbook is written:

> To install this library, run an msdos command prompt in the subfolder
>   "Scripts" of the folder where you installed Python, then type the command `pip install openpyxl`

I have tried to follow some tutorials on youtube but it wasn't clear enough.

now in my terminal is written :

> "WARNING: The directory '/Users/Camelia/Library/Caches/pip' or its
>   parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels
>   has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory.
>   If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. Requirement
>   already satisfied: openpyxl in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
>   (2.6.2) Requirement already satisfied: jdcal in
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.4.1) Requirement
>   already satisfied: et_xmlfile in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
>   (from openpyxl) (1.0.1)"

And when in python I try to run something it's written "from openpyxl import Workbook:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'"

Comment: The equivalent of an msdos command prompt (windows) on a mac is the "terminal" application. Open that and try running the `pip install` command there

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer! i just tried it and now it's written "Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (2.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jdcal in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: et_xmlfile in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.0.1)"

Comment: but when i try to do a python code it is written  "    from openpyxl import Workbook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl' "

Comment: Do you have a python3 virtual env set up?

Comment: sorry , could you be more specific?  i didn't quite understant what is a virtual env set up  i use the IDLE of Python3.7.0 tk version 8.6.8

Comment: i just looked and it seems like no but i'm not sure still

Comment: @Cameliahime *"use the IDLE of Python3.7.0"*: Seem you are running `Python 3.7`, do in terminal: `pip3 install openpyxl`

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU SO MUUUUUUUUUUUUUCH GUYS YOU ARE AMAZING YOU SAVED MY FINALS

Answer (score 1):

Running **pip** by default uses *pip2* which is embedded to *Python2.x*.

Run **pip3** for **Python3.x**:

```
pip3 install openpyxl
```